# Display accurate timezone

Tags: 20.04, date, timezone

```
$ date
Tue 25 May 2021 12:31:56 PM CST
$ systemctl list-timers
NEXT                        LEFT          LAST                        PASSED        UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Tue 2021-05-25 16:39:00 CST 6min left     Tue 2021-05-25 16:09:05 CST 23min ago     phpsessionclean.timer        phpsessionclean.service
Tue 2021-05-25 18:12:30 CST 1h 40min left Tue 2021-05-25 11:39:43 CST 4h 52min ago  fwupd-refresh.timer          fwupd-refresh.service
Wed 2021-05-26 00:00:00 CST 7h left       Tue 2021-05-25 00:00:09 CST 16h ago       logrotate.timer              logrotate.service
Wed 2021-05-26 00:00:00 CST 7h left       Tue 2021-05-25 00:00:09 CST 16h ago       man-db.timer                 man-db.service
```

It's not clear whether CST refers to Cuba timezone, Cameroon timezome, or US Central timezone.

Is it possible for my Linux to spell out the full name of the timezone or use the format of UTC-x?

Answer (score 4):

Use *timedatectl*:

```
sh@balrog:~$ timedatectl 
                      Local time: Tue 2021-05-25 12:41:55 CEST
                  Universal time: Tue 2021-05-25 10:41:55 UTC
                        RTC time: Tue 2021-05-25 10:41:55
                       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```